# Flutter RiverPod: How to add post process which is run every time to FutureProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

In my app, I'm using [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) and [flutter_tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) package to read aloud http response.
Firstly, I added it after fetching the data in FutureProvider like this:

```dart
final futureProvider = FutureProvider.family<String, String>((ref, itemId) async {
  // fetch data from server
  final result = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => "$itemId");
  await SpeakResult(result); // speak here
  return result;
});
```

but it was read aloud ONLY first time even if FutureProvider was called multiple times with same itemId.

Secondly, I added it in `build` method, but it was ALWAYS read aloud when rebuild the widget.

```dart
useProvider(futureProvider("item id")).when(
  loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  error: (error, stackTrace) => Text("$error"),
  data: (value) async {
    await SpeakResult(value);
    return Text("$value");
  },
);
```

Are there any idea to solve this?

Full code is here:

```dart
final futureProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<String, String>((ref, id) async {
  ref.onDispose(() => print("disposed"));
  // fetch data from server
  final result = Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => "$id");
  // await SpeakResult(result);
  return result;
});

final asyncListProvider = StateNotifierProvider((_) => AsyncList());

class AsyncList extends StateNotifier<List<AutoDisposeFutureProvider<String>>> {
  AsyncList() : super([]);

  void add(String id) {
    /*
      //I want to do something like this:
      final asyncValue = futureProvider(id).whenData((value) async {
        await SpeakResult(result);
        return value;
      });
    */
    final asyncValue = futureProvider(id);
    state = [asyncValue, ...state];
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final list = useProvider(asyncListProvider.state);
    return ListView(
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Add data"),
          onPressed: () {
            context.read(asyncListProvider).add("item id");
          },
        ),
        for (final item in list)
          useProvider(item).when(
            loading: () => ListTile(
              title: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
            error: (error, stackTrace) => Text("$error"),
            data: (value) {
              // await SpeakResult(value);
              return Text("$value");
            },
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the beautiful things about using providers is that they are efficient because they only compute the value once unless something changes that would alter that value.

The reason you are seeing the behavior in your first example:

> but it was read aloud ONLY first time even if FutureProvider was called multiple times with same itemId.

is because of the property of providers I mentioned above. If you add an [autoDispose decorator](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose) to your futureProvider I believe this will solve your issue.

Also, the reason it is always being read aloud in your second example is that everything in the build method is always rebuilt when anything changes even if it's not visually obvious. This goes back to my first point about providers being efficient because you don't have to reevaluate the provided value unless you explicitly want that behavior.

Comment: In my full code, all providers are keep listened to show status or result. So I think all of them are never disposed.

Comment: That's the problem, you should add the autoDispose decorator to your futureProvider.

Comment: Edited the code of this issue. I added autoDispose decorator but it was not disposed. And I don't want to dispose this provider. Return cached http response but do post process each time.